# How to Sort Range of rows and colums A To Z using Epplus?

Tags: c#, epplus

[image]

How I can achieve this using EPplus My row ranges are B38:B72 and the column ranges are F38:F72

[image]

How I can select the domain_start, comp1, comp2, comp3, total as per the image want to sort them by large to small using total column.

Comment: I just found it can be done using  wsDashboard.Cells[ownStartRow + 1, ownStartColumns-1, rCount, 5].Sort(5, true); but it is not working, Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Guys finally I achieved it with the following code.

```
mainSheets.Cells[ownStartRow + 1, ownStartColumns, rCount, 6].Sort(4, true);
```

--

In the sort method 4 is index in cell[1,2,3,4];
I hope this will help to some one.